# Having trouble using AJAX to POST to a database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm currently building a mobile app using Cordova and I'm having trouble getting a basic test login function working with my code. I have no clue why this isn't working, and I'm unfamiliar with the convoluted way I have to use php so I'm not even sure how to get proper error reporting from that part of the code. If anyone could help me out, I'd be really grateful.

Code below (I've blanked out some details with asterisks.

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="app">
            <form id="Loginform">
            <p><label>username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="unl" /></p>
            <p>
              <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="pwl" /></p><p>

          </p>
            <p><input type="submit" id="login" value="Login" onClick="logIn();" />
            </p></form>

        <form id="Registerform">
            <p><label>username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="unr" /></p>
            <p>
              <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="pwr" /></p><p>
            <label>Re-type Password
              :</label>
            <input type="text" id="pw2r" />
          </p>
            <p>
            <input type="submit" id="register" value="Register" onClick="regisTer();" /></p>

        </form>
        <input type="button" id="check" value="check" onClick ="checkUn();">
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/localstorage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/logreg.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/camera.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/LaunchMyApp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

logreg.js

```
      function logIn() {
    alert("1");
}

function regisTer() {
    var un = $("#unr").val();
    var pw = $("#pwr").val();
    var pw2 = $("#pw2r").val();

    if (pw!='' && pw2!='' && un!='') {

        if (pw == pw2) {
            alert("run post");
            $.post("http://cs12ars.icsnewmedia.net/Media/register.php", 
            {
                name:un, pass:pw
            }, function() {
                alert( "success" );
                })
                .done(function() {
                alert( "second success" );
                })
                .fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
                })
                .always(function() {
                alert( "finished" );
            });


        } else {
            alert("both passwords must match"); 
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please fill in all fields.");
    }


}
```

register.php (on the server, same server as the database)

```
<?php

//clean input
function clean_string($db_server = null, $string){ 
 $string = trim($string); 
 $string = utf8_decode($string); 
 $string = str_replace("#", "&#35", $string); 
 $string = str_replace("%", "&#37", $string); 
 if (mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $string)) { 
 $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_server, $string); 
 } 
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
 $string = stripslashes($string); 
 } 
 return htmlentities($string); 
}

//encrypt data
function salt ($string) {
        $salt1 = 'gds54d';
        $salt2 = '54h6';
        $salted = md5 ("$salt1$string$salt2");
        return $salted;
}

?>

<?php 

$db_hostname = 'localhost'; 
$db_database = '****'; 
$db_username = '****'; 
$db_password = '****'; 
$db_status = 'not initialised'; 
$str_result = ''; 
$str_options = ''; 
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password); 
$db_status = "connected";
//connect to the database
mysqli_select_db($db_server, $db_database); 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pw = $_POST['pass'];
$password = salt($pw);

$query = "INSERT INTO `bla` (`bla`, `test`) VALUES (NULL, '$name');"; 

mysqli_query($db_server, $query);
mysqli_close($db_server); 
?>
```

Comment: Well, there is obviously a huge number of things that might go wrong here. First, make sure that your POST is even sent by adding _alert_ just before calling _$.post_. If that is triggered, add callbacks for success and failure as described in [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for _$.post_ with alerts in those too to see if execution goes to which one. Start with those and I'll help you after it more.

Comment: I've added error callbacks with various alerts, as well as one before the post runs. The alert (run post) before the post fires off, but none of the callbacks do; neither the success ones or the error ones. Not sure if that means I've done something wrong or if that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have absolutely no idea why, but changing from using $.post to $.ajax and setting asnyc to false made it start working.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://cs12ars.icsnewmedia.net/Media/register.php",
    data: {name:un, pass:pw},
    async: false
});
```